# Setup Ubuntu with differing locale and language settings

Tags: ubuntu, language, setup, locale

Why is it during a setup of Ubuntu / Debian, it is not possible to select a locale that is not strictly related to the selected language? Are there any drawbacks to using a locale setting different from the selected language?

As an example, I'd like to use an international language for the interfaces but keep a local scheme for dates and currencies.

Answer (score 1):

Why? -- No Idea

Any Drawbacks? -- None that I know of.